# Не могу решить задачу на C++. Постоянно выводится ответ 10000, т.е не присваивается значение

Tags: c++, математика, арифметика, теория-чисел

```cpp
#include <iostream>
    
using namespace std;
int main () 
{    
int min =100000;
for (int i = 10000; i > 0; i--) 
{
    for( int n=1; n<20; n++)
    {
        if (i%n==0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else 
        {
            break;
        }
        min==i; 
    }
    cout<<min;
}
```

Comment: Ну а вы попробуйте присвоить разок...

Comment: `==` - сравнение, `=` - присваивание

Comment: а warnings разве не выводятся? должно быть так (в Visual Studio к примеру): `Warning C4553 '==': result of expression not used; did you intend '='?`

Comment: Всё компилируется, проблема с ответом, заменял '==' на '=', ничего не поменялось

Comment: Так вы  сами даете команду continue; и  break; После никакой код не выполнится. Пропускаете остальное, или завершаете цикл

Comment: Я только начал решать задачи, как это должно выглядеть?

Comment: Так вы же не говорите что хотите делать. Как вам ответят как может выглядеть то, не знаю что?...

Comment: 2520 - самое маленькое число, которое делится без остатка на все числа от 1 до 10.

Какое самое маленькое число делится нацело на все числа от 1 до 20?

Comment: А разве после break он выходит из цикла for?

Comment: @dzef, а что, по-Вашему, он должен делать после `break`? Почитайте в гугле, что делает `break`, раз уж так всё плохо и заодно про различие `==` и `=`. И боже, Вы сами видели какой расколбас у Вас в вопросе вместо кода был? Неужели нельзя по-человечески отступы проставить?

Answer (score 2):

А вы оптимист - искать это число до 100000...
Вообще эта задача решается не так - вам нужно наименьшее общее кратное чисел от 1 до 20. К счастью, `int` хватает...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
// На тот случай, если в вашем компиляторе нет
// стандартных функций gcd и lcm...
int gcd(int m, int n)
{
    while(m && n) if (m < n) n %= m; else m %= n;
    return m + n;
}
int lcm(int m, int n)
{
    return m/gcd(m,n)*n;
}

int main()
{
    int N = 1;
    for(int i = 2; i <= 20; ++i)
        N = lcm(N,i);
    cout << N << endl;
}
```